# UIVisualEffectView disappears after adding subview

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview

I have a xib that I've created in Xcode's interface builder. Inside the xib is a UIVisualEffectView w/ vibrancy. If I add a subview to the UIVisualEffectView in any capacity (either in interface builder or programmatically as you can see in the code below), then the subview is vibrant (as it should be) however the UIVisualEffectView is no where to be seen.

So the subviews of the UIVisualEffectView are the only elements visible on screen while the UIVisualEffectView itself is missing.

Before adding any subviews, the UIVisualEffectView appears perfectly fine onscreen.

How can I fix this?

```
import UIKit

class EmptyContentView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var vibrantLabel = UILabel()
        vibrantLabel.text = "Vibrant"
        vibrantLabel.sizeToFit()
        vibrantLabel.center = self.center
        self.visualEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrantLabel)
    }

}
```

Edit: Note, I am testing on a device. iPhone 6 plus running iOS8. In the simulator I see neither the subviews nor the UIVisualEffectView.

Here is how I am instantiating the nib's view.

```
var nibViews = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("EmptyContentView", owner: self, options: nil)
                        let emptyContentView = nibViews[0] as! EmptyContentView
                        emptyContentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: self.tableView.frame.size.height)

                        self.tableView.addSubview(emptyContentView)
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { self.tableView.alpha = 1 }, completion: nil)
```

By the way, animating the tableView or not does not make a difference. The frame for the emptyContentView is also correct.

Note: Turning off vibrancy does fix the issue.